# Make VC++ Recompile All Files

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a simple C++ application using the Visual Studio IDE and the VC++ compiler.

In this application I have an erroneous file that affects the other files as well. When I compile it, as expected I get errors. Now, if I remove all references to the file from my project, and then run it, the compiler will still exit in an error. In the compile message I then see the filename of the erroneous file. The only way to prevent this from occurring is by either removing all contents of that file, or remove the file, and then recompile it.

My guess is, because VC++ is 'smart' it saves compilations and when they are unaffected it doesn't recompile it. But because the erroneous file affects the other files, some compile errors (not all) simply stay.

Does anyone know how to disable such behaviour?

Comment: after you removed the file, did you do "rebuild all"? otherwise files may linger as you correctly pointed out

Comment: @claptrap I simply click "Rebuild" but on the bottom right it says it's rebuilding all, so I guess yes. :s

Answer (score 0):

To recompile all files you can rebuild all, or make a clean build.
Yes VC++ will save compilations if things have not changed, it will probably say up to date.
I don't think that you can disable it, but a clean build should be able to solve it. If that is the entire problem, also check how it is linking things, there you should be able to remove references to files.

The build should be under the build tab.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the errors ?

If the file contains actual functional code then fix the compilation errors ?
If the file does not contain functional code, then what is it doing in your project.

I expect this "erronous" file to be a header (.h) file that is included in other c++ files, so when it tries to compile the c++ files it will generate an error (or more) per c++ file.
If you just remove the file from the IDE project; the compiler will still include the file (because it still exists on disk); and will continue generating errors.

If you actually remove the file on disk, then you will have other types of errors.

In all cases, just fix the compilation errors.

Comment: I would do that but the file is 12 lines and contains a small 10k+ errors.

Comment: The odd thing is, when I simply comment out the lines that the compiler is complaining about, compile, comment them back in, compile, it works fine. (When all references to that erroneous file are removed but the file is still in the project)

Comment: If the file is 12 lines, edit the original question with the 12 lines and add a couple of errors that it generates.

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild and the Visual C++ compiler to an *excellent* job producing a correct binary when you make changes such as adding or removing a file. Chances are, even without a complete rebuild the compiled executable will be correct. If you are seeing unexpected behavior, it is most likely caused by one of the following things:

1. Check that Visual Studio is configured to build your project before running it. Check the following options under **Tools → Options... → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run**:

   - Before building: Save all changes
   - On run, when projects are out of date: "Prompt to build" or "Always build"
   - On run, when build or deployment errors occur: "Prompt to launch" or "Always launch"
2. If Visual Studio asks if you want to run an old version of your program, you may have introduced a compile error by removing the file, so the compiled binary will certainly be out-of-date until you correct it.
3. If your project contains a file that directly or indirectly `#include "yourRemovedFile"`, then removing the file from the project may have no effect.
4. The Visual Studio Errors List reports issues independently from the compiler. You might be seeing old errors reported that are no longer relevant to your project but have not been cleared from the UI yet. In these cases, when you *run* your program you would still get the same results. You can also see if this is your problem by restarting Visual Studio and seeing if the error messages persist.